# PostgreSQL and ArcGIS Pro "invalid entity type" error while opening table

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I can see and select some of polygons from SQL database in ArcGIS Pro but other ones I cannot select. Because of this I cannot see the attribute table of the table which comes from PostgreSQL database. I am using dbeaver for SQL connection. And then I create a new database connection in ArcGIS.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state what geometry types are stored in the table. I expect you have multiple types or an unsupported type.